# VS2019: WINVER macro is wrong for resources compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I have 2 identical projects for VS2010 and VS2019. They inherit ".props" files which among other things define
`WIN32;_WINDOWS;_WIN32_IE=0x0600;WINVER=0x0601;_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601;_WIN32_WINDOWS=0x0601;`
CPP files work well and these definitions are right. RC compiler in VS2010 also works right, but in VS2019 it shows an error
`Error    RC2104  undefined keyword or key name: IDTRYAGAIN`
The reason for this error is that IDTRYAGAIN is hidden:

```
//WinUser.h
#if(WINVER >= 0x0500)
#define IDTRYAGAIN      10
#define IDCONTINUE      11
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0500 */
```

because WINVER is suddently equal to `0x0400`
  It seems that I have identical settings for RC in my projects, command line looks like:
`/l 0x0409 /nologo /fo"my_path\%(Filename).res"`

All the difference that I've found is that in VS2019 there is the point on "Inherit from parent of project defaults" for "Undefine Preprocessor Definitions" which leads to Evaluated value:
`%(UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions)` But as we can see it doesn't affect the command line...
If I implicitly define the required WINVER in RC settings defines VS2019 starts to work fine.
What can be wrong here? Is there some difference in RC-related behavior between VS2010 and VS2019?

UPD.
Logs from VS2010:

```
> Task "RC"
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\rc.exe /l"0x0409" /nologo /fo" my_path\my_res_out.res" my_path\my_res.rc   
1>  Tracking command:  
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Tracker.exe /d C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\FileTracker.dll /i my_path /r my_path\my_res.RC /b MSBuildConsole_CancelEvent31c756f06d7d4121bb209443c669a690  /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\rc.exe"  /l"0x0409" /nologo /fo"my_path\my_res_out.res" my_path\my_res.rc 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winuser.h(9835): warning RC4005: 'LB_ADDSTRING' : redefinition
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winuser.h(9983): warning RC4005: 'CB_ADDSTRING' : redefinition
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(54): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDA'
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(76): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE'
```

Logs from VS2019:

```
> Task "RC"
1>    Task Parameter:Source=my_path\my_res.rc
1>    Task Parameter:Culture=0x0409
1>    Task Parameter:ResourceOutputFileName=my_path\my_res_out.res
1>    Task Parameter:SuppressStartupBanner=True
1>    Task Parameter:UseResponseFile=False
1>    Task Parameter:TrackerLogDirectory=my_path\.tlog\
1>    Task Parameter:MinimalRebuildFromTracking=True
1>    Task Parameter:ToolArchitecture=Native32Bit
1>    Task Parameter:
1>        ExcludedInputPaths=
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\atlmfc\include
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\winrt
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\Include\um
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\arm64\1033
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\1033
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\1033
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\arm64\1033
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\arm\1033
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x64\1033
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX64\x86\1033
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\tools
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\ide
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin
1>            C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin
1>            C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
1>            C:\WINDOWS
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\x64
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\atlmfc\lib\x64
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\lib\x64
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64
1>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\lib
1>    Task Parameter:TrackFileAccess=True
1>    Write Tracking Logs: my_path\rc.write.1.tlog
1>    Read Tracking Logs:
1>    my_path\rc.read.1.tlog
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\rc.exe /l"0x0409" /nologo /fo"my_path\my_res_out.res" my_path\my_res.rc
1>    Tracking command:
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Tracker.exe /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\FileTracker\FileTracker32.dll" /i my_path.tlog /r my_path\my_res.RC /b MSBuildConsole_CancelEventb9a11d84798d4cc392e905b288f0a5ec  /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\rc.exe"  /l"0x0409" /nologo /fo"my_path\my_res_out.res" my_path\my_res.rc
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winuser.h(11682): warning RC4005: 'LB_ADDSTRING' : redefinition
1>
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winuser.h(11830): warning RC4005: 'CB_ADDSTRING' : redefinition
1>
1>    my_path\my_res.rc(90): error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: IDTRYAGAIN
1>
1>    The command exited with code 1.
```

(path and names are omitted to simplify reading )

Comment: You can run your build using the [MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) to investigate, what settings are ultimately passed to the resource compiler. It's next to impossible for Microsoft to change the behavior of a tool as widely use as the resource compiler is. It issue is more likely rooted in your particular project configuration.

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you for advice, I'll try this utility. For now, I've got detailed logs from MSBuild and attached to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource compiler doesn't inherit macro definitions from the compiler: it uses its own set.
I guess in VS2010 it worked well just by luck: order of including of header in WinAPI led to defining default WINVER to appropriate for my project value. Now the order is changed and default value is different
To solve my problem I used explicit definition in props file like:

```
<ResourceCompile>
<PreprocessorDefinitions Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'">WIN32;_WINDOWS;_WIN32_IE=0x0600;WINVER=0x0601;_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601;_WIN32_WINDOWS=0x0601;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
</ResourceCompile>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, and also please feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) yourself.